# Laravel object relational mapping, fetching models

Tags: laravel, orm

I'm trying to fetch two models using relationships 'HasOne' but upon applying conditions, the task model is not being fetched.

I've tried using closure to fetch them but the model is not being fetched

```
public function paps($id)
{
    $paps = Papdailysale::with(['task' => function($query) use ($id){
        $query->where('TeamID',$id);
    }])
    ->where('PapStatus','Assigned')
    ->get();

    return $paps;
}
```

The relationship in the `Papdailysale` model is as given below:

```
public function task()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Techietask::class, 'ClientID', 'ClientID');
}
```

Comment: what model isn't being fetched? ... what result do you actually get?

Comment: I've highlighted in the question. The task model isn't being fetched. returns a null value

Answer (score 1):

1. I think it's because of the table binding. Everything is correctly specified in the `with` method

```php
public function hasOne($related, $foreignKey = null, $localKey = null)

// change foreignKey?
$this->hasOne(Techietask::class, 'ID?', 'ClientID');
```

2. also make sure that the necessary `TeamID` records exist in the database